# Next JS Version 12+: Static Site Generation

Tags: next.js

I'm using Next.js version 12.0.4 on a new project, having used Next.js version 10 on a prior one.

Has something changed with Static Site Rendering at build time? It's rendering all my output pages when I do an npm run build (which in turn executes "next build and next export") with html files that include a ton of .js files and no native text "content" which I'd expect.

That is, the output doesn't have any of the standard HTML `<h1>`, `<h2>` etc. in it, just a bunch of javascript for the client to hydrate.

Prior versions of Next.js (or perhaps it was my configuration?) seemed to render pure, finalized HTML just fine.

I'm trying to render a simple About page (no dynamic routes, no dynamic props for this route) and, while it properly renders a page in the "/about/index.html" output location, that page has a bunch of .js files and a JSON payload. That page does indeed display properly, but I'd really like the output in the "out" directory to be actual .html files with HTML pre-rendered, for SEO and other reasons.

In my next.config.js, I've specified:

```
module.exports = {
  exportPathMap: function () {
    return {
      "/": { page: "/" },
      "/about": { page: "/about" },
    };
  },
};
```

I've also specified getStaticProps on the about page conponent (about.tsx). (I'm using typescript if that matters.)

The rendered /about/index.html file has a ton of .js includes and no real HTML "content".

Have I missed a configuration setting? What can I do to make it render pure HTML where I'd like?

Answer (score 0):

AHA! Ok, so this error was of course a coding error on my side.

In _app.tsx, I had a wrapper for Authentication that I had written. By (bad) design, it was deliberately NOT rendering children for it if the user wasn't authenticated. Therefore, the pre-renderer wouldn't render the "regular" html elements, because the pre-renderer of course does not sign in.

If this same problem happens to you, make sure you're not wrapping all views up in some provider element which conditionally renders children.